# Grails lock insert concurrency issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

how can I lock the whole table when inserting a record using GORM? Will that take more memory and cause perm gem?

Comment: Why would you want to lock a table when you insert a new row?

Comment: 2 users may add same record at the  same time.

Comment: How would 2 users add the same record? 2 users can add *a* record, but it will never be the same. You can add unique indexes to avoid duplicates, if that's what you mean. Locking the whole table to protect agaist this seems overkill and I have never encountered it. It seems far less disruptive to catch the error if the unique index is violated. If there is no unique inde, then 2 rows will be added, it's up to you to enforce it.